# iOS Safari file input [Take Photo] capture = Pano

Tags: ios, file-upload, safari, capture, panoramas

On iOS Safari, and clicking to input a file with accept image/*, I get the [Take Photo] option. When I touch that I'd like the option for Pano, to be available, but it's not.

Basically I created a demo where you can upload an iOS Pano and vie it in 360. Works great, but the user has to upload a previously shot Pano, and not take one realtime.

Was hoping something like capture="pano" or accept="image/*;capture=pano" as the file input's attribute, would do the trick.

Anyone know a way this could be done, or do I need to do a dev request at Apple?